# A complete metric on the subset $[0,1) \cup [2,3]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is this space completely metrizable?  The metric that is inherited from $\mathbb R$ is not complete on $[0,1) \cup [2,3]$ since there are Cauchy sequences that do not converge, e.g. $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$.

This question is similar to the question of why $(0,1)$ is completely metrizable which was answered positively in the following thread...

[Show that $(0,1)$ is completely metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049445/show-that-0-1-is-completely-metrizable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$[2,3]\cup[4,\infty)$ with the subspace metric is complete. And
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{when }x\in[2,3] \\
3+\frac{1}{1-x} & \text{when }x\in[0,1) \end{cases} $$
is a homeomorphism from your space to mine.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess what you want to say is that you can choose a metric on $[0,1)\cup [2,3]$ such that $f$ is a homeomorphism, right?

Comment: @user159517: Being a homeomorphism doesn't depend on a metric, only on the topology. The topology is, of course, the one induced on $[0,1)\cup[2,3]$ by the subspace metric -- otherwise it would be a different topological space than the one the OP is talking about.

Comment: Ah yes, I read the question too sloppily, I thought the goal was just to find a metric on this set such that one has a complete metric space.

Comment: @user159517: The discrete metric would do that much quicker. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A subspace of a completely metrizable space $X$ is completely metrizable if and only if it is $G_{\delta}$ in $X$.